# matrix operations with transpose like properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Has any one studied operations on matrices with transpose like properties - for example (A+B)' = A' + B' where ' stands for transpose.  Also ' is its own inverse.  Is there a common name for such operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a fairly common notion. See [Involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*-algebra).

Comment: You don't have to do it for this answer if you don't want to. But please consider upvoting, in general, answers and questions that you find useful; that's how this site works.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot agree with your answer: assimilating  transposition to  involution is very reductive: it is only  one property of transposition (and in finite dimension : no longer systematically true in infinite dimension).

Comment: Finite dimension? Do you know what a C$*^$-algebra is?

Comment: In infinite dimension, for topological vector spaces, a space can well be not reflexive (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space). But I don't want to polemicate, and as we are here to help students, it is not worth the value. I only say that, if there is a main keyword to be associated with transposition, it is duality (see my modest text that captures so few of what duality is).

Answer (score 0):

Transposition is linked to the vast domain of **duality** : 
let us consider for example a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&5\\-1&1&2\\3&1&2\end{bmatrix}$$

- A classical interpretation of the **columns** of $A$ is in terms of vectors,
- A dual interpretation gives to the **lines** of a matrix  the "status" of coefficients of a plane, for example for the first line the plane with equation $ \ \ 1x+2y+5z=0$, or the family of planes with equations  $ \ \ 1x+2y+5z=k$.  More abstractly, when one considers the function $v \in \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $l_1:(x,y,z)\rightarrow 1x+2y+5z=\langle l_1,v \rangle$ (the last equality being a definition) where $v$ is the vector with components $x,y,z$), using a notation very similar to a dot product.

$l_1$ is called a "linear form" (acting on vectors to give a number). An illustrative example :

In the product of two matrices, the first one can be considered as line gathering", the second as a "column gathering", and the resulting product is

$$\begin{bmatrix}l_1\\l_2\\l_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&v_3\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\langle l_1,v_1 \rangle&\langle l_1,v_2 \rangle&\langle l_1,v_3 \rangle\\\langle l_2,v_1 \rangle&\langle l_2,v_2 \rangle&\langle l_2,v_3 \rangle\\\langle l_3,v_1 \rangle&\langle l_3,v_2 \rangle&\langle l_3,v_3 \rangle\end{bmatrix}$$

Numerically, you will have no difference, but the interpretation of matrices' lines as "linear forms" is one of the iceberg's tops of the very fruitful domain of duality.

Comment: Very good information, thanks a lot.